# Interface EJB bean is not injected in JAX-RS Implementation class?

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, jax-rs, ejb, websphere

I am using WAS 8.5 , RAD 9.0 , JAX-RS 1.1 , Java EE 1.6, EJB 3.0 . There is WebModule(contains rest classes), EJB Module(contain all EJB Implementation classes).
Implementing Rest Webservice using jax-rs , and getting **NullPointerExpection** while PUT Service call.

Below is my code snippet:

Servlet web.xml in Web Module which refers JAX-RS Class in EJB Module.(com.implement.services.RestServiceInvoke)

```
<servlet>
        <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
             <param-value>com.implement.services.RestServiceInvoke1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

JAX-RS Class like

Note: No @ApplicationPath() Annotaion Used.

```
public class RestServiceInvoke1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(ImplementationRest.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Interface Class like:

Note : @Local annotation Included in interface class thats also not working

```
public interface IStudentServices {
 public String getValue(String value);
}

@Stateless
public class StudentServiceBean implements IStudentServices {
   @Override
   public String getValue(String value){
        return value;
   }
}
```

and Service Implementation Class like:

```
@Stateless
@Path("partyservices")
@Resource(name="jdbc/dbname", type=DataSource.class)
public class ImplementationRest implements IEmployeeServices {
      @EJB
      private IStudentServices iStudentSerives;

      @PUT
      @Path("/setprimary")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Override
      public String getValues1(SamplePojo person){
        iStudentSerives.getValue("string");
        return value;
      }
}
```

iStudnetServices.getValue("string") gets NullpointerException. I mean IStudentServices  is not injected from container. Already gone through similar error over web , but no solutions. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ImplementationRest** EJB bean is instaniated using javax.ws.rs.core.Application instead EJB Container.

```
public class RestServiceInvoke1 extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(ImplementationRest.class);
    return classes;
}}
```

This is the reason EJB Bean classes not injected in to anohter Bean that instantiated via javax.ws.rs.core.Application. Afterwards i achieved this implementation by **Spring Framework** like **ejb-local-ref** in web.xml , **jee:jndi-lookup** in bean.xml. Please go through with IBM Support URLs.

Go through below link for Summarizing this issue.

http://wedowebsphere.de/blogpost/accessing-jpa-jax-rs-service-directly

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 common reasons your scenario is not working as expected:

1 - The servlet is not properly obtaining a reference to the EJB. Performing a `new ImplementationRest` does not result in an EJB, but a plain old Java object which will not receive any injection. The servlet would need to either perform a JNDI lookup to obtain a reference to the EJB, or use injection; `@EJB` or `@Inject`.

2 - The application includes the EJB API classes, specifically `javax.ejb.EJB`, as part of the application. When `javax.ejb.EJB` is packaged with the application, and PARENT_LAST classloading is used, the EJB container will not recognize the `@EJB` annotation, since it is loaded with the application classloader and injection will not occur.

I'd guess you are encountering problem #1; probably JAX-RS 1.1 is not recognizing that `ImplementationRest` is an EJB, and is just performing a `new ImplementationRest`.

Comment: Thanks @Tracy for your valuable response.